# How to pass a variable that contains json objects as an externalvariable to execute ansible playbooks?

Tags: ansible

I am unable to pass a variable with json objects to Ansible playbook as extra variable because it's not recognizing the variables.

I am saving the json objects into a variable named "pay" in linux shell.

When I call the ansible playbook using `sudo ansible-playbook test.yml -e "'${pay}'"`

It throws the following error.

"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'username' is undefined\n\

It works when I give pass the json file directly

```sudo ansible-playbook test.yml -e '@payload.json' ``

Could someone help us on this?

Comment: Can you show us what the contents of `$pay` look like? I can't reproduce your problem from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the json as a an external variable then you need to pass the values directly while running the playbook.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html(Passing variables on the command line)

ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"